# SPSS syntax for naming individual analyses in output file outline

Tags: syntax, output, naming, spss

I have created syntax in SPSS that gives me 90 separate iterations of general linear model, each with slightly different variations fixed factors and covariates.  In the output file, they are all just named as "General Linear Model."  I have to then manually rename each analysis in the output, and I want to find syntax that will add a more specific name to each result that will help me identify it out of the other 89 results (e.g. "General Linear Model - Males Only: Mean by Gender w/ Weight covariate").

This is an example of one analysis from the syntax:

```
USE ALL.
COMPUTE filter_$=(Muscle = "BICEPS" & Subj = "S1" & SMU = 1 ).
VARIABLE LABELS filter_$ 'Muscle = "BICEPS" & Subj = "S1" & SMU = 1 (FILTER)'.
VALUE LABELS filter_$ 0 'Not Selected' 1 'Selected'.
FORMATS filter_$ (f1.0). FILTER BY filter_$.
EXECUTE. 

GLM Frequency_Wk6 Frequency_Wk9
    Frequency_Wk12 Frequency_Wk16 
    Frequency_Wk20
/WSFACTOR=Time 5 Polynomial
/METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
/PLOT=PROFILE(Time)
/EMMEANS=TABLES(Time)
/CRITERIA=ALPHA(.05)
/WSDESIGN=Time.
```

I am looking for syntax to add to this that will name this analysis as: "S1, SMU1 BICEPS, GLM" Not to name the whole output file, but each analysis within the output so I don't have to do it one-by-one. I have over 200 iterations at times that come out in a single output file, and renaming them individually within the output file is taking too much time.

Comment: There are probably multiple ways this can be achieved. Could you indicate in a bit more detail the current setup? Is OMS being routed to an Excel export for example?

Comment: Could you edit your post to include enough of your syntax to help understand what operations you are currently using?

Comment: It was the OMS syntax that was of interest here. Can you EDIT your original post to include the syntax rather than post as comment please.

Answer (score 0):

Making an assumption that you are exporting the models to **Excel** (please clarify otherwise).

There is an undocumented command (`OUTPUT COMMENT TEXT`) that you can utilize here, though there is also a custom extension `TEXT` also designed to achieve the same but that would need to be explicitly downloaded via:

```
Utilities-->Extension Bundles-->Download And Install Extension Bundles--->TEXT
```

You can use `OUTPUT COMMENT TEXT` to assign a title/descriptive text just before the output of the GLM model (in the example below I have used `FREQUENCIES` as an example).

```
get file="C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\23\Samples\English\Employee data.sav".

oms /select all  /if commands=['output comment' 'frequencies'] subtypes=['comment' 'frequencies']
  /destination format=xlsx   outfile='C:\Temp\ExportOutput.xlsx'  /tag='ExportOutput'.

output comment text="##Model##: This is a long/descriptive title to help me identify the next model that is to be run - jobcat".
freq jobcat.

output comment text="##Model##: This is a long/descriptive title to help me identify the next model that is to be run - gender".
freq gender.

output comment text="##Model##: This is a long/descriptive title to help me identify the next model that is to be run - minority".
freq minority.

omsend tag=['ExportOutput'].
```

You could use `TITLE` command here also but it is limited to only 60 characters.
You would have to change the OMS tags appropriately if using `TITLE` or `TEXT`.

### Edit:

Given the OP wants to actually add a title to the left hand pane in the output viewer, a solution for this is as follows (credit to Albert-Jan Roskam for the Python code):

First save the python file "editTitles.py" to a valid Python search path (for example (for me anyway): "C:\ProgramData\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\23\extensions")

```
#editTitles.py
import tempfile, os, sys
import SpssClient

def _titleToPane():
    """See titleToPane(). This function does the actual job"""
    outputDoc = SpssClient.GetDesignatedOutputDoc()
    outputItemList = outputDoc.GetOutputItems()
    textFormat = SpssClient.DocExportFormat.SpssFormatText
    filename = tempfile.mktemp() + ".txt"
    for index in range(outputItemList.Size()):
        outputItem = outputItemList.GetItemAt(index)
        if outputItem.GetDescription() == u"Page Title":
            outputItem.ExportToDocument(filename, textFormat)
            with open(filename) as f:
                outputItem.SetDescription(f.read().rstrip())
            os.remove(filename)
    return outputDoc

def titleToPane(spv=None):
    """Copy the contents of the TITLE command of the designated output document
    to the left output viewer pane"""
    try:
        outputDoc = None
        SpssClient.StartClient()
        if spv:
            SpssClient.OpenOutputDoc(spv)
        outputDoc = _titleToPane()
        if spv and outputDoc:
            outputDoc.SaveAs(spv)
    except:
        print "Error filling TITLE in Output Viewer [%s]" % sys.exc_info()[1]
    finally:
        SpssClient.StopClient()
```

Re-start SPSS Statistics and run below as a test:

```
get file="C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\23\Samples\English\Employee data.sav".

title="##Model##: jobcat".
freq jobcat.

title="##Model##: gender".
freq gender.

title="##Model##: minority".
freq minority.

begin program.
import editTitles
editTitles.titleToPane()
end program.
```

The `TITLE` command will initially add a title to main output viewer (right hand side) but then the python code will transfer that text to the left hand pane output tree structure. As mentioned already, note `TITLE` is capped to 60 characters only, a warning will be triggered to highlight this also.

[image]

This editTitles.py approach is the closest you are going to get to include a descriptive title to identify each model. To replace the actual title "General Linear Model." with a custom title would require scripting knowledge and would involve a lot more code. This is a simpler alternative approach. Python integration required for this to work.

Comment: Thank you.  I am not exporting the results to excel.  I am only trying to label 200+ analyses that I am running in the output file so I can scroll through and identify the different iterations within the output file to select the results I need to summarize.  I don't use excel during any part of this work flow.

Comment: The solution posted should still suffice for that purpose also but why the mention of OMS, which is typically used to export result?

Comment: I have changed the heading since I am not using OMS.  I also added an example the syntax I am using, and what type of title I would want to add in the output file.  I mistakenly called it OMS.  I am trying to manage the output file, and incorrectly labeled it as OMS, which upon looking through the SPSS manuals realized that is a separate thing designed for exporting results.

Comment: Have you tried the solution posted OUTPUT COMMENT TEXT? How would you like a solution to be different/improved from that? That the title is shown in the left hand pane instead/also?

Comment: That command adds text to the output (right side of file with results), but doesn't change the title in the output outline (left side of output file).  I want to change the labels in the output outline.

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I was unable to save the .py file to the SPSS extensions folder since that required administrator approval, so I saved it to my Python folder instead.  I then ran the second code and it opened the example Education file, but didn't transfer the Page Titles to the outline/left side of the output.  Instead it gave me a message saying "Configuration file spss.dxcfg.ini is invalid."  I am not familiar with Python or using it with SPSS, so perhaps I did something wrong or missed a step?

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using:

```
SPLIT FILE SEPARATE BY <list of filter variables>.
```

This will automatically produce filter labels in the left hand pane.

This is easy to use for mutually exclusive filters but even if you have overlapping filters you can re-run multiple times (and have filters applied to get as close to your desired set of results).

For example:

```
get file="C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\23\Samples\English\Employee data.sav".
sort cases by jobcat minority.
split file separate by jobcat minority.
freq educ.
split file off.
```

[image]